# How to do modulo (%) operations on values in exponential form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to do modulo operation on values in scientific notation, or exponential form.

I have stored the numbers `1x10^13` and `5*10^9` in this form:

```
const first_value = [
 1, // x*10^y, this is x
 13 // x*10^y, this is y
] // this is 1*10^13
const second_value = [
 5, // x*10^y, this is x
 9 // x*10^y, this is y
] // this is 5*10^9
```

I'm trying to compute the equivalent of the integer modulo of the two numbers (`10000000000000 % 5000000000`) *without* first converting the operands into integers, as the numbers involved could exceed the largest value that can be accurately represented as an integer in JavaScript.

I don't want to use BigInt() because for some reason it cannot be stored in JSON files.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not at all clear what your question is about.

Comment: @Pointy He wants to compute `1^13 % 5^9` but with the number stored in two-element pairs, rather than actual integers.

Comment: @user229044 your powers of divination are worthy of respect :)

Comment: no `1 * 10 ^ 13 % 5 * 10 ^ 9`

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, sorry, scientific notation, I accidentally omitted the `*10`

Comment: `while removing the Number.MAX_VALUE limit`  you will want to use BigInt's for this eg.  `10n**13n % 10n**9n`

Comment: without using bigint

Comment: `BigInt() because for some reason it cannot be stored in JSON`,  just serialise first then,  there are lots of things that can't be stored in JSON, eg. binary, so we use Base64,  BigInt so we use string..  `(10n**13n % 10n**9n).toString()`

Comment: Are there any constraints on the coefficient?

Comment: @Keith That's not useful. There is no reason to use BigInt and arbitrary precision math for this, it's not a programming problem, it's a math problem. You can just *look* at the numbers in their scientific notation form and tell if they're divisible.  https://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/fyp/mathrev/mr-scnot.html

Comment: @user229044  `That's not useful. `  Any reason for the rude remark, sure if there is a way of doing this with using the exponents, great stuff, I have no issue with that.  But this works using BigInt without any issues.  `it's a math problem.`  then blow me for answering using a coding one.

Comment: To answer this we need to know whether the coefficient is always an integer, or if it can have a fractional part. In either case the answer can be found in a few steps and the exponential part can be discarded completely. 10^x  is *always* divisible evenly by 10^y if x is greater than y.

Comment: Assuming both `x` and `y` are integers. You could convert them to `BigInt` during the calculation. Then turn the result back into `[x, y]` form when the calculation is completed. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/b7b63c424291109122ada420a97f036b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the minimum of the exponent values and subtract both exponen by this value, get remainder and multiply by the min exponent.

```
     |
10000|000000000
    5|000000000
     |
```

```js
const
    fn = (a, b, c, d) => {
        const min = Math.min(b, d);
        return a * 10 ** (b - min) % (c * 10 ** (d - min)) * 10 ** min;
    }
    
console.log(fn(1, 13, 5, 9));
```

Comment: This would fail if tested with huge values: `fn(4, 1e6, 1, 3e5) // NaN`.

Comment: yea, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Best to write a function to convert scientific -> BigInt

Careful, BigInt and Integer cannot be used interchangably.

```js
const scientific = (coefficient, exponent) => {
    return BigInt(coefficient) * 10n**BigInt(exponent);
}

const first_value = [
 1, // x*10^y, this is x
 13 // x*10^y, this is y
] // this is 1*10^13
const second_value = [
 5, //x*10^y, this is x
 9 //x*10^y, this is y
] // this is 5*10^9

const modulo_value = scientific(...first_value) % scientific(...second_value)

console.log(scientific(...first_value)) // 10000000000000
console.log(scientific(...second_value)) // 5000000000
console.log(10000000000000 % 5000000000) // 0 (regular int)
console.log(modulo_value) // 0 (BigInt)
```